# Avoiding EADDRINUSE when using wallaby.js with an express project

Tags: node.js, express, testing, wallaby.js

I've had great luck using wallaby.js on client side JavaScript and I'd like to try to get it to work on my server side JavaScript. However, wallaby.js likes to spin up a lot of parallel web servers which causes problems for the tests because it keeps on throwing `EADDRINUSE` errors.

The basic scaffolding of my project was done with the Yeoman [angular-fullstack generator](https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack), so my server code sits in `/server` and most of the methods are in `/server/api`.

Thus far, I've managed to get it to kinda work with the following configuration:

```
module.exports = function () {
  return {
    files: [
      'server/**/*.js',
      { pattern: 'server/**/*.spec.js', ignore: true }
    ],

    tests: [
      'server/**/*.spec.js'
    ],

    env: {
      type: 'node',

    },

    debug: true,
    workers: {
      initial: 1,
      regular: 1,
      recycle: false
    }
  };
};
```

Here you can see that I'm setting the number of wallaby workers to 1 and not allowing it to recycle workers. It works fine the first time through, but after I start to edit files I get occasional `EADDRINUSE` errors.

Is there a preferred mechanism for using wallaby.js with express and avoiding it from spawning multiple test server processes all on the same port, thereby eliminating the `EADDRINUSE` errors?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The name is a bit confusing, but `recycle: true` will do trick. `recycle: false` means that once started node processes will be reused forever.

I understand it's not always possible to use parallel processes (especially with DB tests), but to make it work for a web server, you may specify 0 as a port when running tests, so it'll pick and use a random one.

```
  var server  = require('http').createServer();
  server.listen(0);
```

This way wallaby will be able to run your tests in parallel and reuse processes.

Comment: Excellent. Having Wallaby set my `NODE_ENV` variable to `test` so my app listens on a random port and removing everything in the `workers` property made it work well.